# A proof of the completeness of PLTL (Propositional Linear Temporal Logic)

Tags: reference-request, linear-temporal-logic

In what paper(s), textbook(s), and/or classnote(s) can I find a detailed proof of the completeness of a certain proof system for PLTL (Propositional Linear Temporal Logic)?

Comment: Logics aren't complete but proof systems are. Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: @Kai The proof system. Where can I find a detailed proof that a certain proof system of PLTL is complete?

Comment: Sorry, I meant _which proof system did you have in mind_? Got a reference?

Comment: @Kai I'm especially interested in Fred Kroeger's system as delineated in chapter 5 *The Formal System $\Sigma_{\textrm{TA}}$* of his textbook *Temporal Logic of Programs* (Springer 1987). He presents a detailed proof of its completeness in chapter 6 (Theorem 6.10 on p. 36), but I think the proof is incorrect, so  I'm looking for other proofs. (More accurately, it is the proof of Theorem 6.9 on the Satisfiability of $\Sigma_{\text{TA}}$ which I deem incorrect, but the completeness proof makes use of it.)

Comment: What's your issue with the proof of Kröger's Theorem 6.9? (Mind you, Kröger's $\mathcal{L)_{\mathrm{TA}}$ is not exactly LTL but I believe they are equally expressive.)

Comment: @Kai The error in the proof of Theorem 6.9 occurs in the 4th and 6th cases, when $F \equiv \circ A$, and when $F \equiv A\ \textbf{atnext} B$, respectively. The errors are similar in nature, so let's consider the former case.

The justification provided for the 2nd '$\Leftrightarrow$' is: "by ind. hyp.". However, in order to apply the induction hypothesis to $A$, it must be shown that $A\in\tau(\mathcal{F}_{i+1})$. Unfortunately, this membership needs not hold, by the definition of the $\tau$ function on p. 31 (specifically case 4 of $\tau$'s definition).

Comment: Not sure I follow. By the ind. hyp. (which I believe is implicitly universally quantified over $i$) we have that equivalence. So if indeed $A\notin\tau(\mathcal{F}_{i+1})$, then we learn that (in that model) we do not have $\mathrm{\mathbf K}_i(F) = \mathrm{\mathbf t}$. Why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The proof system "DUX" in [*On the temporal analysis of fairness.* D Gabbay, A Pnueli, S Shelah, J Stavi. POPL 1980](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/567446.567462) is perhaps closest to what you're after. Being a conference paper, the completeness proof is rather terse but with a bit of luck you can fill in the details.

Comment: I'm interested in a detailed proof, not a terse one. But this is better than nothing. Thanks.